# Grafana Alerts: Monitor multiple linux services using a single query

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I am using Prometheus and Grafana alerting for monitoring Linux services. I use below query to get a count of all running services and send an alert if the count is less than the expected number.

```
services.count(node_systemd_unit_state{name=~"A.service|B.service|C.service", job="job1", state="active"} )
```

I wanted to know if there is any way I can find out which service is not running( or list of services which are running) as a part of the alert. I am using email alerting which currently sends me count of services which are running.